# align a div in a footer to the other div

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck with this its the problem

```
<div id="example1">
    <div id="example2"> </div>
    <div id="example3"> </div>
</div>
```

I need to align the div with id `example3` under example 2 and if it's possible just in the footer and center of the div with id `example1`. how can i do it?? i have days trying and more close it's like this.

**CSS**

```
#example3{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin:0;
height:80px;
position:absolute;
top:170px;
}


#example2{
height:153px;
width:305px;
float:left;
background:url(Logo.png);
}
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the CSS you have I think you need to swap the div that's absolutely positioned to the "logo" (#example2), then you can just margin the top of example 3 to get the top 170px spacing

#### Example : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/cKzPk/)

try:

```
#example1{
    background: #eee;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

#example2 {
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height:152px;
    width:305px;
}

#example3 {
    background: #007;
    color: #fff;
    width: 300px; /* adjust to suit */
    height: 80px;
    margin: 170px auto 0 auto;
}
```

if you don't know the width of `#example3` - and so can't use the `auto` left and right margins - then you can center it another way by changing it to `display: inline-block` and setting `text-align: center` on `#example1`

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, `position:absolute` won't let you set margins.

For another, you've got

```
margin:0;
```

which is resetting your `auto` on the left+right.  Try

```
margin:0 auto;
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/steve/Evc6Q/) which accomplishes what you're trying to do (more or less).

**EDIT**

OK, but now you've now introduced a third problem, in the `float:left`, which will override the `auto` margin and always float left.

Also, the problems I mentioned above haven't been addressed. To summarize: no floats, no absolute positions, and try not to override the margin by styling it twice.

Are you trying to have a 17px space between `#example2` and `#example3`?  Here's an updated link, evolved from the last one, that does this new behavior: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/steve/AF8ca/)

Comment: thanks for your help but i'm edited the question and put the style of div 2. i'm looking for a property i don't know if exit's